How to set type of Array inline in Swift?
For example, I have 2 enums:
enum MyEnum1WithLongName {
  case a, b, c, d, e
}

enum MyEnum2WithLongName {
  case a, b, c, l, p
}

I want create array inline with type, some like this:
if <MyEnum2WithLongName>[.a, .b, .c].contains(currentStatus) {
  // do something
}

instead of:
if [
     MyEnum2WithLongName.a, 
     MyEnum2WithLongName.b, 
     MyEnum2WithLongName.c
   ].contains(currentStatus) {
  // do something
}

But my attempt to creating array with type like this:
<MyEnum2WithLongName>[.a, .b, .c]

doesn't work for Swift. I tried searching how to do this but found only how I can create variable with type array. I would appreciate it if you could help me with this seemingly easy question, but which I could not figure out by myself.

I think what you're looking for is this...
Array<MyEnum2WithLongName>(arrayLiteral: .a, .b, .c)

But it's not very standard.
You can also do...
if [MyEnum2WithLongName.a, .b, .c].contains(currentStatus) {
  // do something
}

And it will infer the types after the first.

Maybe a bit contrived but if you use a high-order function with a closure then it's enough to define the type of input parameter(s) to the closure to make the compiler understand the type of the array
[.a, .b, .c].contains(where: { (value: MyEnum1WithLongName) in
    value == currentStatus 
}) 


You can add type annotations in the middle of expressions with as, e.g.
if ([.a, .b, .c] as [MyEnum2WithLongName]).contains(currentStatus) {
  // do something
}

That might not be the best idea, though. If the group of .a, .b and .c together has some significance in your domain, then you're better off giving that a name. For example
enum NetworkStatus {
    case offline
    case lanButNoInternet
    case online

    var isOnline: Bool {
        switch self {
        case offline:          return false
        case lanButNoInternet: return false
        case online:           return true
        }
    }
}

if currentStatus.isOnline {
    //...
}

